# Syntax error when executing batch of statements via PDO but fine via SSMS

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pdo

I'm writing code to create a MSSQL database from scratch using PHP PDO. I have the database created, and now need to execute a bunch of statements loaded from a .SQL file to create the tables, data, etc. The first few lines are

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'myDbName', 120
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
BEGIN
EXEC [myDbName].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
END
GO
ALTER DATABASE [myDbName] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'myDbName', 120

...
```

If I run the .SQL file directly in SSMS, it runs perfectly. If I load it and execute it via PHP PDO, I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.' in ...
```

Looking at the profiler, my query is being prefaced/wrapped with

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel ''myDbName', 120
...
```

and it appears that with the prepared execution wrapper, the server doesn't like it. I'm executing the script that I load from the SQL file with

```
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$serverName.';Database='.$databaseName, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
$db->prepare($mySqlScript)->execute();
```

How can I fix the syntax error to execute the entire set of commands PHP loads from the SQL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to split your script by the "GO" clause into multiple statements, then run them one by one.

Something like:

```
$script = file_get_contents('script.sql');
$statements = explode( 'GO', $script );
foreach( $statements as $statement ) {
  // here execute the $statement
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
  $sth->execute();
}
```

This is what SSMS do internally, splits the statements by the "GO's" before execute them.

Comment: Great, thanks. It had cross my mind as a hack, but not as the required way. Do you know what the reasoning is behind not being able to dump the whole script in? I would have thought for performance issues it would be better to be able to process everything in one go.

Comment: Probably it was not one of the library's goals and it's a behavior easy enough to implement, so it was left for us to handle it. You can code it like `function execScript( $scriptPath ) { // Do the split and the execution }` and in your code handle it like if was part of the original library. It's what the library will do (more or less) any way.